# AWS Lambda start with higher concurrency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

I have a lambda function with an average run time of 0.8 seconds and call it about 200 times (Invocations). By the end, it has a concurrency of 3, but it creates a small bottleneck in my event-driven process. Is there anyway I can start this process off with more than 1 lambda running as a standard, instead of the relative slow scaling up in this instance?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-concurrency-for-lambda-functions/

Comment: Just be wary of the costs - provisioned concurrency will mean having x instances of your function running constantly, whether they're invoked or not.

Comment: @luk2302 Provisioned keeps functions initialized, but I was looking for a way to call multiple instances of the lambda from the start.

Comment: That's what provisioned concurrency is for. Lambda takes a while to scale up from its cold start.

Comment: Either you scale up or you are always warm / provisioned already. There is no middle ground.